# invalid assignment to const 'setMessage'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am having this issue with TextField from Material UI. I am trying to change state with React with the props onChange. Sadly I keep having this message **"invalid assignment to const 'setMessage'"** I use the same code that I have use in other components of my code so I really don't know why now I can't use setMessage.

```
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(""); 

                <TextField 
                    name="message" 
                    placeholder="Écrire un message..."
                    onChange={ e => 
                        setMessage=(e.target.value)
                    }
                    onKeyPress={(event) => {
                        event.key === 'Enter' && sendMessage();
                    }}
                />
```

Comment: You need to _call_ `setMessage`, not assign to it. Compare your example to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). _"I use the same code that I have use in other components of my code"_ - no you don't, otherwise they'd have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the `onChange` prop. You should remove the `=` from this line

```
setMessage=(e.target.value)
```

The `onChange` prop should look like this

```
onChange={ e => 
    setMessage(e.target.value)
}
```